# negating filter condition with NA present gives counter-intuitive result

Tags: r, dplyr

I have stumbled across the behaviour of `dplyr::filter` in a complex statement on a large dataframe, which basically comes down to the treatment of `NA` values:

```
df <- tibble(a = c(rep(1,3), 
               rep(NA, 3)))

A tibble: 6 x 1
      a
  <dbl>
1     1
2     1
3     1
4    NA
5    NA
6    NA
```

Filtering for rows that equal 1 gives the expected result:

```
df %>% filter(a == 1)

A tibble: 3 x 1
      a
  <dbl>
1     1
2     1
3     1
```

Filtering for rows that do not equal 1, I would expect the remaining 3 rows of the df to be returned, which is not the case, however:

```
df %>% filter(!a == 1)

A tibble: 0 x 1
 ... with 1 variables: a <dbl>
```

So while in the first case `NA` is interpreted as not equaling 1, in the second case, it is interpreted as equaling 1. Is there a logic I am missing here?

I know I can use `%in%` to get the expected result:

```
df %>% filter(!a %in% 1)

A tibble: 3 x 1
      a
  <dbl>
1    NA
2    NA
3    NA
```

but it seems strange to me to use this operator with just one element (rather than a vector).

So my questions to the experts: Is this the intended behaviour of `filter`? Is it common practice to use `%in%` when negating a filter condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the behaviour of `%in%`, not `filter`.

Let's use a simple example:

```
a = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA)

> a == 1
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA   NA
> a != 1
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA
> !(a == 1)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA
```

We see that when we use the relational operators `==` or `!=`, NA values in the input remain NA in the output. However...

```
> a %in% 1
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> !(a %in% 1)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

With the `%in%` operator, NA values in the input become FALSE in the output. Since this is supposed to be the more intuitive interface for `match()`, let's take a look at that as well:

```
> match(a, 1)
[1]  1  1  1 NA NA NA
```

So nope, `match()` itself doesn't behave this way, at least not with the default arguments. However, the help file `?match` explains:

> `%in%` is currently defined as
>   `"%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0`

There you have it. When we use `a %in% 1`, we are actually doing the following:

```
> match(a, 1, nomatch = 0L)
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0

> match(a, 1, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Hence `filter()` returns rows with NA values when the `%in%` operator is used together with `!` negation.

Comment: Ok, I see. So the counter-intuitive behaviour (at least to me) is that '==' yields 'NA' if the data value is 'NA'. I would rather expect that 'a == 1' yields 'FALSE' with 'NA' data, because 'NA' does not equal 1. I will have to remember using '%in%' in negated conditions like this. Thanks for your answer!